# Why does my controller stop working in GTA V after opening Steam overlay?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v, controllers

I have GTA V for PC, bought through Steam.  I play with an Xbox 360 controller.  When I'm playing the game, if at any point I or the game opens a Steam overlay (be it the text input or the regular overlay), when I return to the game NONE of my inputs work anymore.  Not the controller, not my keyboard.  I can open task manager and close the game but the game just stops accepting input.  Has anyone else experienced this or know of a way to fix/prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Happens the same to me but i found the solution: When you are at the Steam overlay just go back to the first menu, and don't leave any other screen open. Then it will work again.

Seems to be some unsovled bugs with the Steam overlay.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of more reasons:

- The Steam overlay "keeps" the controls for itself - this could be considered a bug/glitch (report?).
- The overlay is the active part - try terminating the program (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> --> Task Manager --> Steam program --> end program (on Windows)) If it still doesn't work, I don't know.

Comment: That's a cool idea, I'll have to try that if I encounter it again.  I don't really play anymore :P